# Data field Null CRM 2015 C#

Tags: c#, dynamics-crm-2011, dynamics-crm, crm, dynamics-crm-2013

My code :

```
OrganizationServiceProxy service = OrganizationServiceProxy();
            QueryExpression qe = new QueryExpression();
            qe.EntityName = "account";
            qe.ColumnSet = new ColumnSet(new string[]{"accountid","name"});
            DataTable table=new DataTable();
            table.Columns.AddRange(new DataColumn[] { new DataColumn("accountid"), new DataColumn("name") });
            var Compte = service.RetrieveMultiple(qe).Entities.ToList();
            foreach (var item in Compte)
            {                    table.Rows.Add(item.Attributes["accountid"].ToString(), item.Attributes["name"].ToString());
            }
            comboBox1.DataSource = table;
            comboBox1.ValueMember = "accountid";
            comboBox1.DisplayMember = "name";
```

my data is like that :

```
         +---------------------------------------+---------------+
                    accountid                          name
         +---------------------------------------+---------------+
            87906183-dbbb-4754-afc9-f2cfcab4942d    Lois Wright
            86a9c978-e1dc-40e2-98cd-6b463ded0f2d      Null
            8e242301-6c97-4509-9031-7237c1d7b14e    Wanda Torres
            2704b13c-8900-4216-98ce-6b03a056ed32      Null
            55f0db83-d4a7-426a-ac7a-a113118b9a1f    Howard Woods
         +---------------------------------------+---------------+
```

I get error  **"The given key was not in the dictionary crm"**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have two records in your example that have "null" for the "name" field. When you query CRM, it only returns attributes that have data. In this case, you need to check the response to make sure it contains a name attribute before you try to use it:

```
if (item.Attributes.Contains("name")) {...}
```

You can also use the GetAttributeValue method, which will return null if the attribute doesn't exist instead of throwing an exception:

```
var name = item.GetAttributeValue<string>("name");
```

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg326129.aspx